# SSRS 2008 R2 Check if external image exists on report server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working on an SSRS 2008 R2 report and I'm displaying images dynamically. I would like to hide the image box and display an icon with text that reads "Image not found" if the image doesn't exist on our report server.

I've tried a few things with expressions, but I can't get them to correctly return true or false, based on if the image exists or not.

The expression I'm using to display the image is:

`="/BusinessIntelligence/Drilldown Reports/" + Fields!item.Value + ".jpg"`

To test if I could get the report to detect whether the image existed, I dragged a textbox onto my report and tried the following expressions in an attempt to return `True` or `False`.

`=IIf(IsNothing("/BusinessIntelligence/Drilldown Reports/" + Fields!item.Value + ".jpg"), "Woohoo!", "Do'h!")` this always returns False, even if the image exists.

I even tried using some custom code I found [here](http://thecrmgrid.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/ssrs-checking-an-external-image-exists/).

Code:

```
Function IsValid(ByVal Url As String) As Boolean 
Dim sStream As IO.Stream 
Dim URLReq As Net.HttpWebRequest 
Dim URLRes As Net.HttpWebResponse 
Try 
URLReq = Net.WebRequest.Create(Url) 
URLReq.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials 
URLRes = URLReq.GetResponse() 
sStream = URLRes.GetResponseStream() 
Dim reader As String = New IO.StreamReader(sStream).ReadToEnd() 
Return True 
Catch ex As Exception 
Return False 
End Try 
End Function
```

And the expression I used for that code is:

```
=IIf(Code.IsValid("/BusinessIntelligence/Drilldown Reports/" + Fields!item.Value + ".jpg"), "Woohoo!", "Do'h!")
```

But this also always just returns false.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS: Report loading external images, image not found, can I hide the image control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688826/ssrs-report-loading-external-images-image-not-found-can-i-hide-the-image-cont)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I needed this thanks.

Your error here is you are using a reserve word for a webpage IsValue.  Change your function name to IsThere and it should work famously.