# Including help documentation in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a complex report using SSRS. I am going to release it to the business users shortly. I have also written a help documentation to help the users which is in pdf format now. As of now I am planning to save this pdf file in a shared location and I will provide a hyperlink in report pointing to that location. Is that a good way or Are there any other better solution? 
Because I am afraid someone may remove/relocate that file in the future.

Comment: Seems about as good as any other way. Drop box, work network would all have the same problem.

Comment: You could set up the report with default parms so it displays and in the header has a link to the help doc. Then they can click on it (use an action on the text box) to get to the file. I read this link if you wanted to check if the file exists, you could do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433023/ssrs-2008-r2-check-if-external-image-exists-on-report-server